# Remote desktop into remote desktop

Tags: rdp

I have a stupid quesition.
I have access to machine X.X.X.X. This machine is in the same network with the machine I need to access.
I can connect to X.X.X.X and then connect to needed machine, but I do not want that. Is there a way to connect to that machine without connecting to X.X.X.X? (I do not have permissions make any changes to the network)

If it is possible, how many connections can i have simultaneously? Example:

```
User 1 - X.X.X.X.
User 2 - Y.Y.Y.Y.
User 3 - Z.Z.Z.Z.
```

(X's, Y's, Z's are in the same network)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Igiko, and work via web-browser. It includes the built-in RDP Gateway (need to install on one machine in the network) and a web tunnel - cool thing if you have no direct IP address and cannot configure provider’s NAT. Free version is for 2 machines.